# How to iterate through excel sheet using AppleScript?

Tags: excel, applescript

I'm new to AppleScript, so this may or may not be an obvious question. I need to iterate through an excel spreadsheet, where each row is one device, and the columns are pieces of information about that device I need to get. Essentially it'd be a nested for-loop, where I go through the rows, and for each row I go through all its columns. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your approach. This is not a Wishlist. Please show what you have tried and where you're stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. This will do that:

```
 set NumOfColumns to 5
    set NumOfRows to 5

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        tell document 1
            tell worksheet 1

                --to iterate through rows
                repeat with z from 1 to NumOfRows

                    --to iterate through columns
                    repeat with i from 1 to NumOfColumns

                        --to set a value (here it is adding a number "i as a string". 
                        --I know, you are not asking how to set a value, but here it is anyway!)
                        set value of column i of row z to (i as string)

                        --to retrieve a value (here it is copying the number to a variable ValueX)
                        set ValueX to (value of cell i of row z)
                    end repeat

                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much for your help. If you don't mind me asking, are there any resources you recommend for learning Applescript?

Comment: A bit older, but still very helpful, from the man himself: https://www.amazon.com/Apple-Training-AppleScript-Sal-Soghoian/dp/0321149319/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=80HF9PMJ6467HK5E420V

Comment: Constantly up to date, you can check this out, https://macscripter.net, which should help a lot.